# I need to create a loop that fills an array with each loop through user input

Tags: arrays, c, loops

here's my code,

```
  int main()
  {
  char name[32];
  int grades[20];
  int grade;
  int j;
  char unkstr[]= "Unknown";
  float avg;
  int c;

  begin:

  printf("Welcome to the student Quiz Calculator Program.\n");
  printf("Enter student name: ");
  fgets(name, 32, stdin);
  name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';

  if(strcmp(name, unkstr)==0)
  {goto end;
  }
    for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
    {
    printf("Enter quiz grade %d\n", j);
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    grades[j] = grade;
    }
    avg = grades[1]+grades[2]+grades[3]+grades[4]/4;
    
     printf("Average Quiz Calculations for %s grade1: %d grade2: %d grade3: %d grade4: %d is       %f.\n", name, grades[1], grades[2], grades[3], grades[4], avg);
    while ((c=getchar()) !='\n' && c !=EOF);
   goto begin;    
        
   end:
   printf("Have a nice day!");


return 0;
}
```

---

I need to loop this array back and fill in grades by 4's through user input, but I don't understand how to loop back the code and fill in a different set of number into the array without the previous set getting in the way. it seems simple in my head but I don't have the experience to figure it out. I'm am very new at this and it sucks. This is C btw. Thank you for the help!

Comment: "*loop this array back and fill in grades by 4's through user input*". It's unclear what that means. For example, what does "by 4's" mean? Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: One thing to note: `for(j=1;j<=4;j++)` Array indices in C start from 0 not 1. So that will leave an unintialised `grades[0]` entry.

Comment: do not use `goto`

Comment: Replace `begin:` with `while(1) {`;  `goto begin;` with `}`; and `goto end;` with `break;`  (You can also use `for(;;) {` instead of `while(1) {`)

Comment: `grades[1]+grades[2]+grades[3]+grades[4]/4;` in not the average.  `(grades[1]+grades[2]+grades[3]+grades[4])/4.0f;` is the average.

Comment: So the user is suppose to input a student name and 4 quiz grades (quiz 1, 2,3, etc), the program should repeat until 'unknown' is entered, then the program will output the average of each quiz from each student at the end and terminate. thank you for all the inputs, I am gonna update it and take out the goto and fix the average equation. thank you